# Using Dispatch from win32com.client 'SAPI.Spvoice'

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to use Python code to change WIN10 text-to-speech voice from Windows Default to English.

There are mentions of using SetVoice commands with SAPI.Spvoice, but cannot find the expample

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
Windows_Speak = Dispatch('SAPI.Spvoice')
Windows_Speak.Speak('Tomato')
```

The above code would use the Windows default language settings, but I need to be able to change languages using in-Python commands. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
Windows_Speak = Dispatch('SAPI.Spvoice')

Windows_Speak.Voice = speak.GetVoices().Item(2)
Windows_Speak.Rate = 3
print(speak.GetVoices().Item(2).GetDescription()) #just to see what voice is used

Windows_Speak.Speak('Tomato')
```

Play around if the voice id

Comment: the speak part in speak.GetVoices().Item(2) seems not to be recongized (name 'speak' is not defined)

Comment: replace `speak` with `Windows_Speak`. Note that the first (default) voice id is 0. Documentation of `Spvoice` is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms723602(v=vs.85))

Answer (score 0):

One alternative could be using '**pyttsx3**.
If you are trying to change voice from your Window's default one, then you can use try this:

```
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
#with given method you will get the list of voices available
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
#in engine I am setting 0th indexed voice as my custom
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30936782)